# Controlling vertical space after headline when using \parskip

Tags: spacing, sectioning, parskip

When using a 0 length `\parindent` and an expandable length of `\parskip` it is my feeling that the space after section headlines becomes too big (see example). Is there another command I should use for decreasing the vertical space after section headings or should I perhaps use a completely different approach to accomplish what I am after?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt, onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\begin{document}

    \allsectionsfont{\sffamily}

    \section{Lorem ipsum}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse mollis
    ultricies porttitor. Mauris iaculis dignissim magna, sit amet viverra enim
    feugiat consectetur. Ut at mauris in felis congue mattis. Nam molestie mattis
    erat sit amet eleifend. Nulla volutpat ornare quam. 

    Pellentesque at varius libero. Nunc quis nunc eget elit congue pulvinar non
    sagittis turpis. Fusce mauris lorem, euismod accumsan sollicitudin dictum,
    adipiscing dignissim tortor. Aliquam commodo cursus sapien placerat
    volutpat. Mauris dignissim sem vitae magna fringilla hendrerit.

    \setlength{\parindent}{0 em}
    \setlength{\parskip}
              {1 \baselineskip plus 0.2 \baselineskip minus 0.2 \baselineskip}

    \section{Dolor sit}
    Phasellus non odio nec arcu aliquam cursus. Integer at sem id magna
    lobortis ultrices. Morbi sed lacus neque, vitae aliquet massa. Aliquam vel
    ligula orci.  Nam at velit libero. Vivamus ac commodo velit. Mauris cursus
    ultricies sapien et egestas. Donec non augue ut nisi luctus pretium.
    Vivamus laoreet varius lacus at feugiat. Phasellus condimentum tincidunt
    egestas. Aenean eu aliquam sem. 

    Cras libero nunc, mattis quis aliquet vel, faucibus fringilla nibh. Etiam
    commodo sem et arcu eleifend tincidunt. Maecenas pulvinar odio id turpis
    feugiat ac sollicitudin nulla sollicitudin. Pellentesque habitant morbi
    tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque
    non felis ligula, in interdum justo.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rather general problem, since `\parskip` is always used, when there is a `\par` somewhere. This often has very strange side effects, also after environments and math formulas.

The [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/memoir.html) class has a special length called `\abnormalparskip` that can be used to introduce space between paragraphs and not after every other object. It is not perfect, but much better.

Comment: Is it just me, or does pulling in the big (I just found a 500 pages pdf) memoir thing seem like an overly complicated way of solving something that (at least at first glance) looks very simple?

Comment: Yes. It is a very complex document class that has many more features features than you might need. The problem is, that you need to introduce a length that gets inserted after paragraphs but not everywhere where TeX ends a paragraph (by issuing `\par`) The memoir class might be overkill. Maybe someone else has a solution that works with every class.

Answer (score 2):

There are also some packages which supports a user interface for setting the lengths. However, you can also overwrite the existing definitions, e.g. for `section` (can be found in article.cls):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt, onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
       \setlength{\parindent}{0 em}
    \setlength{\parskip}
              {1 \baselineskip plus 0.2 \baselineskip minus 0.2 \baselineskip}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
      {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
      {0.2ex \@plus.1ex}% <=== space after
      {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \allsectionsfont{\sffamily}

    \section{Lorem ipsum}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse mollis
    ultricies porttitor. Mauris iaculis dignissim magna, sit amet viverra enim
    feugiat consectetur. Ut at mauris in felis congue mattis. Nam molestie mattis
    erat sit amet eleifend. Nulla volutpat ornare quam. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, then I have to this for all used section levels. It is probably not worth it...

Comment: @jonalv: maybe ... on the other hand it is simply a copy and paste ...